# Vim quickfix mode with Oracle Pro*C files?

Tags: c, oracle, vim, oracle-pro-c

when using Vim to compile an Oracle Pro*C file i have following issues:

1. if nothing is wrong the compilation ends but the current open file is gone turning the screen empty (this only happens with Pro*c files, regular .c work fine), hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> navigates to the original file.
2. if there is a problem on the code i can open quickfix window but when i position myself over the line that shows the location with the problem it won't do anything.

I am fairly new with Vim so i don't know how to tackle those issues.

Any advise is appreciated

I am using vim 7.3 if it helps.

Comment: You're not talking about the QuickFIX engine for FIX protocol, are you?

Comment: hello Grant Birchmeier, nope, i mean the quickfix for Vim.
Upon further investigation am guessing my problem is realated to the errorformat configuration, right now am trying to find if anyone has already build one configuration that works with PRO*C compiler output

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Vim associates `*.pc` files to another file format (by default) and does not come with an [`errorformat`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#error-file-format) pattern that is suitable for Oracle Pro*C's baroque warning/error message style (at least when using Vim 7.2 or 7.4).

(Your first issue is a result of the default `errorformat` matching the Pro*C startup message and the 2nd issue is because the default `errorformat` patterns does not match any Pro*C warning/error messages.)

I use following additional `errorformat` patterns for Pro*C files:

```
"append patterns for Pro*C multi line error message:
set efm+=%ESyntax\ error\ at\ line\ %l\\,\ column\ %c\\,\ file\ %f:,%ESemantic\ error\ at\ line\ %l\\,\ column\ %c\\,\ file\ %f:,%EError\ at\ line\ %l\\,\ column\ %c\ in\ file\ %f,%ZPCC%[A-Z0-9-]%#\\,\ %m,%C%.%#

"prepend ignoring string to ignore Pro*C startup message
set efm^=%-GPro*C/C++:\ Release%.%#
```

You can add those lines to your `~/.vimrc`.

To fix the related issue of filetype detection you can configure the correct filtetype:

```
$ cd ~/.vim
$ mkdir ftdetect
$ cd ftdetect
$ cat > pc.vim
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.pc  set filetype=esqlc
```

For indentation this is not enough, though.

Assuming something like

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

in your `~/.vimrc` you can explicitly configure C indentation rules:

```
$ cd ~/.vim
$ mkdir indent
$ cd indent
$ cp /usr/share/vim/vim72/indent/c.vim esqlc.vim
```

Without that I don't get any indentation at all in `.pc` files - not even of the C code.